# Вложенные транзакции и многопоточность

Tags: android, многопоточность, sqlite

Есть синхронизация с сервером. Запускаются пару потоков, которые запрашивают данные и записывают каждый в свою таблицу с помощью транзакций. Возможно ли обеспечить атамарность всей синхронизации с помощью внутренних транзакций или другим способом?

**Простой пример**:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
            try {
                ...
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }.execute();
```

Бд лочится и на втором `db.beginTransactionNonExclusive()`(если нет транзакции, то на вставке данных) поток останавливается. Коннект к базе один. `yieldIfContendedSafely()` вроде должен помочь, но он возвращает false.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то Вас интересует штука под названием "Критические секции". Также, как и Вы, первый раз столкнулся с этим при использовании нескольких потоков, которые оперировали одним и тем же кодом в работе с базой данных. в JAVA предусмотрено решение в виде `synchronized`  метода. Если это то, что Вам нужно, то, думаю нагуглить труда не составит)

Comment: С синхронизацией знаком и видимо не уловил вашу мысль.
Нужно что-то вида:
1. Открыть транзакцию.
2. Запустить потоки.
3. Если потоки отработали без ошибок, то закрыть транзакцию, иначе откатить вообще всё.